# Epson Stylus printer won't recognize original cartridge

Tags: printer

I have an Epson Stylus TX115. I recently changed the black cartridge with an original one, but it didn't print that good. Seemed that the printer was dirty or something.

I took out the cartridge and cleaned the ink sockets by blowing air with a syringe (since the print head cleaning didn't work). When I plugged the cartridge back in, the printer stopped recognizing it as original.

What could have happened for the printer to stop recognizing the cartridge and how could I fix this?

Comment: This question doesn't directly relate to computers, and is therefore off topic.

Comment: Will it run a clean cycle now? Did you get any error messages?  Was an 'ignore' option offered?  I've read discussions of similar situations saying an ignore option was available but you had be quick to accept it.

Comment: @Mark Szymanski I do think it belongs here, since printers relate directly to computers, as they wouldn't work without them. But still, can you tell me where else should I be asking about this? Thanks.

Comment: @JRobert Haven't seen an Ignore option anywhere. I will try to run a clean cycle again.

Comment: @Pablo: They do not. You can use a printer completely separate from a computer.

Comment: @Mark Szymanski fine, you win that one (I'm thinking digital cameras, or use as copying machines, for instance). But it's also true that a printer is a standard part of many desktop computer setups, so it's not an uncommon and unrelated peripherial (just as webcams). Again, any idea where else should I be asking this one?

Comment: @Pablo: I'm not sure if there are any alternative sites for questions like these.